# Rails 3, How to split actions on the same controller between two devise accounts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I split actions between two devise accounts ? so that each account can view only specific set of actions on the same controller ?

Is there an easy way to redirect the wrong account to a specific view ?

Here is my scenario:

I have created two accounts types:

- Instructor
- Student

There is a controller which both accounts types can visit specific actions on it:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  # instructors are allowed to view all action's views, except :browse_courses, :register_course
  before_filter :authenticate_instructor!,
                :except => [:browse_courses, :register_course]

  # students are allowed to view only :browse_courses, :register_course
  before_filter :authenticate_student!,
                :only => [:browse_courses, :register_course]
```

...

but, strangely, some times, when I visit the edit action at the controller above using instructor account, devise will ask for student authentication, and the edit view won't be rendered, although instructor is able to view the edit

Notice that `before_filter :authenticate_student!` states that :only => [:browse_courses, :register_course] shall be authenticated for student account, so, why edit action gets authenticated too for student ? ( it will show student sign in view )

Is the code above the right way ? or there is a better approach for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is an **authentication** tool. Don't try to implement **authorization** with it.

Let Devise identify your users, and use something else to handle their privileges. I, personally, like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by Ryan Bates.

With it, your controller would look like this:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def browse_courses
    authorize! :show, Course # throws exception if not authorized

    # proceed here
  end

  def register_course
    authorize! :register, Course

    # proceed here
  end
end
```

CanCan has pretty easy and powerful way of defining who can do what. Read this: [Defining Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities).

Comment: Thanks Sergio, but, shouldn't it be 
authorize! :show, CoursesController 
instead of
authorize! :show, Course ? as show is an action for CoursesController, right ?